# Validation windows application

Tags: c#, .net

i would like to know which is the best way to inform the user about his mistakes when entering data...

Show messagebox describing the first found error?
red the textboxes etc?

showing messages on the form(avoid messageboxes)...

Comment: it depends on what you use: WinForms or WPF

Comment: This is an extremely broad question and depends almost entirely upon the stakeholders and/or project owner responsible for defining the features of the system. In some cases a validation summary highlighting a list of errors in a form is appropriate. In other cases a message box may be the most appropriate way to provide that information. As a result, this question isn't easy to answer from a technical perspective as it is more in the realm of user experience. Could you provide more specifics about your business case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [Enterprise patterns and practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx)

There is validation block, easy to implement and integrate to your applications.

Answer (score 1):

Find the application that is the common one that your user uses.  See how it's done there.  Mimic it and make your user happy and un-confused.

Sometimes by using control libraries there are pre-defined ways to display error messages, for example little red (!) signs in the fields on the form that are sensitive to mouse - display pop-up hint with the error text.